# Getting error when reusing my own defined class using import statement

Tags: java, reusability

I have created a class with name 'Minn' in a package in G: drive.
And now i want to use this class in a class which i am defining inside another folder of G:drive.
So,i am importing that package.
But the error shows package doesn't exist.

Below is the code.

**Minn.java**

```
package packa;
import java.io.*;
class Minn {

     public int min(int a[],int x) {
        int minimum=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(int i=0;i<x;i++) {
            if(a[i]< minimum)
                minimum=a[i];
        }
        return minimum;
    }

}
```

**Tes.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import packa.*;
class Tes {
    static int a[];
    public static void main(String s[]) {
        a=new int[10];
        Random r=new Random();
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            a[i]=r.nextInt(30);
            System.out.println(a[i]+" " );
        }
        new Tes().call();
    }

    void call() {
        int ret=new Minn().min(a,10);
        System.out.println("min is "+ret);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `package` statement in `Tes` class ?

Comment: Do i need to keep Tes also in  a package ??

Comment: On my computer, it is able to find the class, but says that `Minn` is not public, and so cannot be accessed from outside the package. Try making the class `Minn` public.

Comment: Even after making it public isn't working.

Comment: which IDE do you use?

Comment: using command prompt to run and editing in sublime.

Comment: Show the structure of your G: drive

Comment: thanks,i got the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to import a class from another project, you have to add It to the Build Path in project properties.

If your project is inside the Workspace, just choose "add class folder".
If it's outside your workspace, use "add external class folder".

Hope that helps.